# Navigation's back stack is lost when navigation is nested

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I have a navigation which looks like this

```
Frag1 -> Frag2 -> Frag3
```

Inside `Frag2` there is a `NavHostFragment` with its own navigation

```
InnerFrag1 -> InnerFrag2
```

If I do this

1. Navigate to `Frag2`
2. Navigate to `InnerFrag2` inside `Frag2`
3. Navigate to `Frag3`
4. Go back

then I'll see `InnerFrag2` inside `Frag2`, when I press back normally I would go from `InnerFrag2` to `InnerFrag1` inside `Frag2` but now it's going to `Frag1` instead.

Here is my navigation handling inside `Frag2`

```
    private val backPressedCallback = OnBackPressedCallback {
        navHostFragment.navController.navigateUp()
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        requireActivity().addOnBackPressedCallback(backPressedCallback)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        activity?.removeOnBackPressedCallback(backPressedCallback)
        super.onDestroyView()
    }

    private val navHostFragment: NavHostFragment
        get() = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.innerNavHostFragment) as NavHostFragment
```

When going back to `Frag2` the fragment in the nav host is the correct one, but navigating back moves away from `Frag2` because inner nav host's back stack is lost. Can I persist it somehow or fix it some other way?

**EDIT:** actually when going from `Frag3` to `Frag2` I see `InnerFrag1` inside, the both look alike, that's why going back at this point brings me back to `Frag1`

**EDIT2:** I found my problem, I inflate `Frag2`s navigation from code in `onViewCreated` like this

```
    val navHostFragment = (frag2NavHostFragment as? NavHostFragment) ?: return
    val inflater = navHostFragment.navController.navInflater
    val graph = inflater.inflate(navigationId)
    navHostFragment.navController.graph = graph
```

setting it in xml makes it work, I still need to set it from code somehow, `Frag2` chooses which navigation to use depending on its arguments

Now my question changes from `Navigation's back stack is lost` to `How to preserve NavHostFragment's state when settings it's graph from code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into this for a little, original question doesn't make much sense, I'd delete it but it got 2 upvotes ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

I solved my problem by adding a check before inflating graph, so that `NavHostFragment`'s graph is set only if it doesn't already have one.

```
    try {
        navHostFragment.navController.graph
    } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
        val inflater = navHostFragment.navController.navInflater
        val graph = inflater.inflate(navigationId)
        navHostFragment.navController.graph = graph
    }
```

`NavController.getGraph` doesn't return null, instead it throws `IllegalStateException`, hence the weird check

Answer (score 1):

You can now handle `onBackPress` on fragments. In your fragment just add this in `onViewCreated` method.

```
val navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                navController.popBackStack(R.id.fragmentWhereYouWantToGo, false)
            }
        })
```

I would also give a check to `app:popUpTo` , `app:popUpToInclusive` or `singleTop` XML attributes to the fragments inside your `Frag2`

Comment: I knew I could handle back presses in Fragments, I have back press handling in the code I posted